# SQL Trigger to copy data to table with more number of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a table (tableA) that has about 150 columns and I would like to copy data from tableA to another table (table B) upon any new data that is inserted to table A. tableB has the same table structure as tableA with a few additional columns.

I am new to triggers and I was reading an example in the following link: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25600/Triggers-SQL-Server

Since I have tableA which has 150 columns, is there any easier way to specify the columns in the trigger rather that declaring 150 variables, selecting 150 variables to equal to the inserted value, and then inserting it to tableB. This makes the trigger code really long. I am wondering if there is any easier way to specify the 150 columns.

Thanks

Comment: First off, that's entirely the wrong way to write a trigger. You don't declare 150 variables (or any), and then select into them, to insert into another table. That's just broken and slow and wasteful. You just insert directly from the 'inserted' collection into the other table. Yes, you should still list out every column (best practice), but you don't declare any variables. Triggers don't execute "per row", but per event... inserts, updates, and deletes can all affect multiple rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple copy trigger should look something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger ON MyTable
FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MyOtherTable (Column1, Column2, Column3... Column150)
       SELECT (Column1, Column2, Column3... Column150)
       FROM inserted;
END
```

Having a table with 150 columns is a problem and not good design at all. That said, it's what you have to deal with. You will need to list out each one individually in both the INSERT and SELECT statements. That will be a one time pain, but it's really the best/only way of doing this. By doing this, you ensure the right data gets into the right column, and nothing breaks if/when columns are added to either table.

To help with the tedious part of creating the list of columns, you can use some SQL like this to generate the list for you:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
SET @sql = N'';
SELECT @sql += QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + N', '
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
 WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable'
SELECT @sql;
```

Just substitute the name of the table with the subset of columns you wish to copy for "MyTable" and you should be good. This of course, assumes the matching columns have the exact same names in both tables. If there are any differences, you'll need to manually align the ones that should get the appropriate data.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and I would definitely use this.

Comment: Would it be possible to write something like this: 

INSERT INTO MyOtherTable (@sql)
       SELECT (@sql)
       FROM inserted;

Comment: No. You must list out the explicit column names in your SQL. You can't use a variable there. So just copy the list of column names from running the second block of SQL and you should be good to go.